# How to increase MySQL performance with joins

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, join, select

I have a MySQL database with InnoDB engine. Particularly one of my queries became very slow. The query is shown below:

```
SELECT t1.`ARTREF1` 
FROM `lijnen` AS t3 
  INNER JOIN 
    (`kortingen` AS t2, `raiproduct` AS t1) 
  ON (t1.LEV=t3.LEV 
  AND t2.LEV=t3.LEV
  AND t1.KCP1=t3.SPLC
  AND t2.SPLC=t3.SPLC 
  AND t1.LEV=t2.LEV 
  AND t2.SPLC=t1.KCP1
  AND t1.`ARTREF1`='".$xartc."' 
  AND t2.ALDOC='".$supcodec."' 
  AND t3.BVNR='".$bvnr."'
    )
```

How it works:
I get through SOAP webservice an XML document. In the XML document I get the article number and supplier number and I query my database to see if the article exists.
It takes nearly  5 to 8 seconds to show the results on screen.

I use indexes on the rows which I search. Every day I purge empty fields to optimize my database
How can I increase the speed of the query?

Some database and hardware information:

- `raiproduct`: 1.500.000 rows
- `lijnen`:  4100 rows
- `kortingen`: 1200 rows
- CPU: 4 cores
- Processors: Intel 64bit hexacore (6 cores) 2.5 Ghz
- RAM: 4096 MB
- SWAP RAM: 1024 MB

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: Try doing EXPLAIN on this query and look what it really does.

Comment: Can you show us an create table structure and an explain. this information about an query wont help that much